Microstrip PCB Design
I am designing a microstrip PCB with frequencies ranging from 100MHz to 8GHz.
There are no significant issues at lower frequencies, but the signal loss becomes quite high as approaching 8GHz.
Especially The signal loss is pronounced when passing through the SP4T switch.
Below is the Artwork around the SP4T. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my design or if there are areas that need improvement.

The switch I used is the PE42441E-Z.
The impedance matching was done as follows:

The top layer is Rogers 4003c with 8mil thickness, and combined with FR4 to produce a 1.6mm thick board.
Here is an actual photo of the PCB.


The signal is passing along the red line, and at 8GHz, there is approximately a 5dB loss.

S11 for the red line
I used the ZNL20 VNA made by Rohde & Schwarz to measure S21.
There is LTCC and MM8030-2610RJ3(Test Point) between the switches.
But I have changed LTCC to 0 ohm to check the path loss.
The trace width is 0.43mm and the copper thickness is 0.018(mm).
Also there is no ground plane cut-outs under the pads of the switch chip.
Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

what's the S11 of the device, in all switching positions?

What instrument are you using to measure insertion loss? If it's a VNA, what calibration method is used and what are the reference planes? What are the other two devices that are in the indicated signal path between the switches in your 4th image? What is your trace width? What is the copper thickness? Are there any breaks in the ground plane on L2 (under the trace or just nearby)? Any ground plane cut-outs under the pads of the switch chip? (Preferrably edit the post to include these details rather than answer in comments)

The switches contribute with 2.4dB @ 8GHz. Anticipate an additional 1dB because of the LTCC filter and another dB of loss from the microstrip line and you are already close to 5dB.

@Neil_UK I added the S11 in the post.

@ThePhoton What is L2?  I can't find it. And I added as much as I can for your questions. Please check and let me know if you need more information.

L2 is the 2nd copper layer in your design.

@Raonoke You are right. As I calculate again, The path loss is not too different than as what datasheet said. But I still want to find something I can fix to improve.

@ThePhoton Oh I see, then what does it mean 'break in groud plane'? Sorry I am not familiar with English term.

Is the ground plane complete with no openings, or are there holes or slots in the copper below the L1 traces?

@ThePhoton There are via holes through all layers.
